# How to display absolute and percentage value in single column in crosstab pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, crosstab

For example, this data was taken from [here](https://datagy.io/pandas-crosstab):

| Type | Children's Clothing | Men's Clothing | Women's Clothing |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Region |  |  |  |
| East. | 113 | 122 | 176 |
| North. | 85 | 89 | 142 |
| South | 45 | 39 | 53 |
| West. | 42 | 41 | 53 |
| Total. | 285 | 291 | 424 |

So, now I want the data in this format

| Type | Children's Clothing | Men's Clothing | Women's Clothing |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Region |  |  |  |
| East | 113 40% | 122 42% | 176 42% |
| North | 85 30% | 89 30% | 142 32% |
| South | 45 15% | 39 13% | 53 13% |
| West | 42 15% | 41 15% | 53 13% |
| Total | 285 100% | 291 100% | 424 100% |

Can somebody help me with this, please?

Comment: So you want each cell to be strings like "113 40%"? Why?

Comment: Just to show both absolute and percentage value for the particular column

Answer (score 2):

IIUC,

```
output = df.astype(str).add(" ").add(df.div(df.loc["Total"]).mul(100).round().astype(int).astype(str).add("%"))

>>> output

Type   Children's Clothing Men's Clothing Women's Clothing      Total
Region                                                               
East               113 40%        122 42%          176 42%    411 41%
North               85 30%         89 31%          142 33%    316 32%
South               45 16%         39 13%           53 12%    137 14%
West                42 15%         41 14%           53 12%    136 14%
Total             285 100%       291 100%         424 100%  1000 100%
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works. But why did we remove Total. Can we keep Total and calculate based on that value?

Comment: @BadCoder - See the edit.